Django logout template not working even with POST
This is my logged_out.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Logout
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'login' %}", method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}

This is my urls.py file

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('accounts/logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='logged_out.html'), name='logout'),
]

view.py
@require_POST
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, "registration/logged_out.html", {})


I've followed the docs to make the /logout a POST and I still get 405 error saying it's a GET request. How do I solve this?

<form action="{% url 'login' %}", method="POST"> This form is confusing.  The button says "Logout", but it sends you to the login url??

Also, why is there a comma after action="...", ?  That does not belong.

This question is similar to: Django built in Logout view `Method Not Allowed (GET): /users/logout/`. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The issue that you are sending the POST request to the login form here:
<form action="{% url 'login' %}", method="POST">

it should be something like this:
logged_out.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
    Logout
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'logout' %}", method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}

and the views.py to be:
def user_logout(request):
    if request.POST:
        logout(request)
        return redirect('login')
    return render(request, "registration/logged_out.html", {})

in this case if when the user accessing the logout page using GET request it show him Logout button when he clicks on it, it will logout him then redirect the user to the login page

Applied this change, i still get
Method Not Allowed: /accounts/logout/
"GET /accounts/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0

the issue was naming the path "logout". i changed it to "loggout" and that seemed to work.
really weird as i've seen other tutorials and posts accept "logout" as the url path

Weird, but glad to hear that it is solved
